# Hidden iframes are triggering page hit counter

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an intranet site with two hidden iframes that are made visibile once a user clicks on the corresponding nav menu option on the parent page. Both of these iframes point to pages I have created and contain code for page hits. I used lazy loading for each of these, and that prevented the iframe from incrementing their respective page hits until the page/iframe was actually made visible; but running Edge in IE Mode has now nullified that. Loading the site now increments all page hits regardless if the iframes are visible or not.

I've searched all over for any tips or tricks to get this working in IE Mode, but I haven't found anything yet. This all works perfectly in Chrome and Edge, but my company is running Edge with IE Mode; so here I am....  in search of answers. Thank you in advance!

Comment: How did you implement lazy loading?

Comment: I set lazy loading as an attribute within the iframe tag --> loading="lazy"

Comment: It's an experimental property and even the newest browsers don't support it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#browser_compatibility

Comment: Thanks for that. I see that Chrome and Edge do support it, and it did work until we implemented IE Mode in Edge. Regardless, I'm guessing there's no way to prevent a hidden iFrame from triggering a page hit.

Comment: You can try using `IntersectionObserver` polyfill and add iframe src by js.